# Captions on Tables Not going on Top Latex

Tags: formatting, latex, caption

For some reason, my captions for my tables are not going on the top of the table as I would like. Instead they are defaulting to the bottom of the table.

Does anybody have any ideas for changes I can make to ensure the caption is on the top? I suspect there is something going on in my preamble that I'm missing.

Here is my code for the table

```
    \caption{Summary Statistics} 
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\hline
    \textbf{Variable} & Min & Max & Mean \\ 
    \hline
Racial Diversity & 0.01 & 0.52 & 0.23 \\ 
    \hline 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{%
    \begin{minipage}{7cm}%
        \small
%Table includes all variables in the analyses in Table 3 \& 4. 
    \end{minipage}%
}\\
\label{descrip}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Here is code for my preamble

```
% Layout
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}



% Citation style
\usepackage{harvard}

% Figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
%\documentclass{memoir}
%\newsubfloat{figure}


% Tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}



% Algorithms
\usepackage[boxed,longend]{algorithm2e}

% Math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% Typography
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textcomp}

% Macro support
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

% Diagrams
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz} % extensive form game trees
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % calculating TikZ coordinates
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % arrows for theory diagrams
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

% PDF links
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % backref=page

\input{common/layout}

\input{common/macros}

%References
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\usepackage{quotchap}
%\fancyhf{}
%\afterpage{\cfoot{\thepage}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{
  font={\sffamily\bfseries},
  labelsep=0pt,
  labelwidth=\transcriptlen,
  leftmargin=\transcriptlen,
}

\newlength{\transcriptlen}

\NewDocumentCommand {\setspeaker} { mo } {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
  {\expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{\item[#1:]}}%
  {\expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{\item[#2:]}}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
  {\settowidth{\transcriptlen}{#1}}%
  {\settowidth{\transcriptlen}{#2}}%
}

% Easiest to put the longest name last...
\setspeaker{PI}
\setspeaker{Deb}[Deb]
\setspeaker{Jack}[Jack]



\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

% How much of a gap between speakers and text?
\addtolength{\transcriptlen}{2em}%

\newcolumntype{x}{>{\scriptsize\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}X}


%
```

Comment: can you please make a [mre] that we can compile instead of these code fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Captions of tables are above the table by default. However amongst the hundreds of packages you load, many of them multiple times and with contradictory options that result in errors that prevent compilation of your document, is the `floatrow` package. Either remove it or configure it to place the caption above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=above}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Summary Statistics} 
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l c c c}
    \hline
    \textbf{Variable} & Min & Max & Mean \\ 
    \hline
    Racial Diversity & 0.01 & 0.52 & 0.23 \\ 
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{%
      \begin{minipage}{7cm}%
        \small
        %Table includes all variables in the analyses in Table 3 \& 4. 
      \end{minipage}%
    }\\
    \label{descrip}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```